# Express does not accept null as valid JSON body (body parser middleware)

Tags: node.js, json, express, jsonparser

I using Nodejs `v14.16.1`, Express `4.17.1`
Have set up the following parsing middlewares in my app:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Im trying to pass `null` as a body to my request:

```
> PATCH /api/v1/trusted/erp/users/+359878206067/vehicles/CM0001AM/inspection HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> Content-Type: application/json
> User-Agent: ricotec.herokuapp.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 4

| null

* upload completely sent off: 4 out of 4 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< X-Powered-By: Express
< X-Request-Id: f5e6241c-0291-48ae-aee7-8e227cf0a06a
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1213
< Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2021 20:38:22 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5


* Received 1213 B chunk
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

and the response I get is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at createStrictSyntaxError (/home/riko/Documents/dev-soft/software/apps/api-v1/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
> at parse (/home/riko/Documents/dev-soft/software/apps/api-v1/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
> at /home/riko/Documents/dev-soft/software/apps/api-v1/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
> at invokeCallback (/home/riko/Documents/dev-soft/software/apps/api-v1/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
> at done (/home/riko/Documents/dev-soft/software/apps/api-v1/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
> at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/riko/Documents/dev-soft/software/apps/api-v1/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
> at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

Now, I know passsing `null` as JSON body is not the most common thing to do when writing to a JSON API, but it doesnt change the fact that `null` is a valid JSON text as per [rfc7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) .
`JSON.parse(null)` for example works just fine on browser or Node.js.

Why Express JSON body parser does not accept primitives `null`,`false`,`true`?
These are valid JSON texts, arent they?

Comment: You can pass `strict: false` in the options, then the parsing is the same as `JSON.parse` https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#strict

Comment: @cbr

You are absolutelly right! Thank you!
BTW, any Idea why have they left it `true` / `strict` by default?

Comment: (although even with that, it's still worth asking yourself why you're sending `null` at all, because the old "just because you can, doesn't mean you should" almost certainly applies here)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
May be you are tright, may be I shouldn't send primitve values, but Im trying to learn something here. So why should I not?
What if I want to set a property to null?
POST /users/Chuck Norris/inventory
and then in the body I would say `null`
instead of listing all inventory items with `null` values.

Comment: No idea: without a description of why you think you need to send `null`, there is very little to comment on, other than the fact that if you _are_ sending just the text string `null` and treating it as a JSON payload, that's almost certainly not a good way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
I edited my previous comment with a use case

Comment: You wouldn't, you'd create dedicated route handling for that, like `/users/{...}/inventory` that you'd call without a payload using the DELETE verb, not GET or POST ([different verbs map to different express `app` functions](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html), so you can have the same route, but one for `app.get`, one for `app.post`, etc).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
Make sense